# I have no idea what my teacher is asking. recursively iterate through subdirectories

Tags: file, recursion, iterator, iteration

For this assignment, you will recursively ite

Comment: [We are not here to do your homework](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266270/specific-warnings-to-newbies-about-homework-code-writing-please-debug-and-sscce)

Comment: All you've done is copy your assignment.  That's your teacher's question, addressed to you.  What do you expect the SO community to do, write your code for you?  What is **your** question?

Comment: If you don't understand your assignment, ask your instructor to clarify it for you. However, the numbered paragraphs explain exactly what recursive iteration through the directories means and how to accomplish it. Perhaps more effort reading the assignment would help.

Comment: Also, in the future tag your question with the language you are using (Java).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the assignment is to write a method to print the contents of a directory, and for each item in the directory that is itself a directory, recursively call the same function to process that one, ....

It didn't say in what order the items need to be traversed (do all files first, then directories, do all directories first, then files, alphabetically), so it seems like you can just get a list of directory contents, printing each file out, and making a call to the function from within itself (recursive call) for each directory.

Comment: I think this is the answer the askers question.  Though, given his difficulty with recurse and iterate, you might want to replace the word traverse.  A quick mention of what recurse and iterate mean might be helpful too.  This must be a very early programming student